# Python linear search not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, search, linear-search

For some reason this python linear search will not work. Every time I run it and input a value that is in the list, it does not tell me that the item is in the list and just runs through. 
It does not give any syntax error so must be something logical. Any ideas?

```
def linearSearch():
numbers = [3, 5, 54, 6, 17, 8, 32, 65, 87, 54]
pointer = 0
print("What would you like to search for?")
searchTerm = input()
try:
    val = int(searchTerm)
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter an integer")
    linearSearch()
while pointer < len(numbers):
    if numbers[pointer] == searchTerm:
        print("Item has been found at " + pointer)
    else:
        pointer = pointer + 1
```

Comment: What did you see when you ran it with a debugger?

Comment: Why don't you try using the index functionality in python ? numbers.index(val) ??

Comment: Why not just use `numbers.index(int(val))`?

Comment: You create a variable `val`, but you never use it after its assignment. Is that intentional? Also, it's not a great idea to do input validation with recursion; see [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/953482) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
if numbers[pointer] == searchTerm:
```

I think you meant to write:

```
if numbers[pointer] == val:
```

`searchTerm` is a string (assuming we're in Python 3.X), so it will never compare equal to any of the integers in the list.

Additional problems:

- You can't concatenate a string and an integer, so `"Item has been found at" + pointer` will crash. Try using `print("Item has been found at", pointer)` instead.
- Your loop prints "Item has been found at..." infinitely, because you don't increment `pointer` when you find the item. Try adding a `break` after the print.
- If the user doesn't enter an integer, you call `linearSearch()` again. But the original call is still on the stack, and will continue to execute once the inner call completes. Then it will crash with `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'val' referenced before assignment`, because `val` was never successfully created in that context. Consider a non-recursive approach, for example:

```
def linearSearch():
    numbers = [3, 5, 54, 6, 17, 8, 32, 65, 87, 54]
    pointer = 0
    print("What would you like to search for?")
    while True:
        try:
            val = int(input())
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter an integer")
    while pointer < len(numbers):
        if numbers[pointer] == val:
            print("Item has been found at", pointer)
            break
        else:
            pointer = pointer + 1

linearSearch()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `val` which is an int and not `searchTerm` which is a string when you compare with `numbers[pointer]`.
Plus, don't forget to break your loop, else it will run indefinitely!

```
if numbers[pointer] == val:
        print("Item has been found at " + str(pointer))
        break
```

**edit** Also added a `str(pointer)` because it will thrown an error in Python3+ when you try to add int with string.

Answer (score 0):

**Linear Search :**

```
 // funtion which rturns true if item found inside list.
    def linearSearch(list, value):
            for i in range(len(list)):
                if i == value:
                     return True
```

// Call above function pass list of values and item to search

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
item = 10
print(linearSearch(list, item)) // item to search
```